# How to find native code in a Cordova - Android Project

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, 64-bit, native

I am customizing SAP's Fiori Client , which is a Apache Cordova application. I added an external library(.aar) to it and rebuilt the android project. I am able to use the generated APK in my devices . When I upload this application(apk) to Google Play , its rejecting the upload as "The application does not comply with 64Bit requirement" . My Gradle version - 2.14.1

When I analyze the generated APK file, it has 2 folders under lib **amreabi-v7a & x86** , under these folders I could see 3 **.so** files.
[APK Analyze - LIB Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjFb7.jpg) 

I haven't written any C/C++ code in the whole project. All I wrote was Java and JavaScript code ( for Cordova ) .
**My question is**  How can I back track the native code from these **.So** files ? How should I approach to generate an apk( or App bundle ) so that I can upload to Google Play successfully.

**Alert :** I am not Android developer, but managed to do till here with other Q&A from StackOveFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is the native code, but the build rules that build 32 bit and 64 bit ABI by default. Do you have access to source for the app and/or the aar? If so look in build.gradle file, and restrict the 32 bit builds by introducing an abiFilter at the scope listed below.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
             // Tells Gradle to build only arm64 and x86 64 ABIs and package
             // them into your APK/library.
            abiFilters 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
       }
    }
}
```

I should add that for a cordova application, the build rules are most likely in a file called build-extras-app.gradle in the cordova project directory. this file will be injected into the android/app/build.gradle file along with cordova's own rules to build the app.